# A bash scripting problem

Tags: bash, scripts

In advance , I'd say I know the basic syntax of bash scripts but the following statement is not recognized for me :

```
if [ ! -f /etc/debian_version ]
```

could you help me what this condition going to work ?
Thanks.

Comment: That line on its own will error out, can you give a bit more context for this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tests whether the file "/etc/debian_version" exists and is a regular file.

Comment: Could you explain more ?

Comment: Square brackets are used for conditional test. Using -f in it means to check whether the file exists and is a regular file. Finally, ! stands for not operation

Comment: Thanks, I think that's it, I'll mark your answer as the correct answer :)